# Firebase phone number authentication on web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I tried this code for making Firebase phone number authentication:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>
            Firebase Phone Number Auth
        </title>
        </head>
        <body>
            Updated
            <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase.js"></script>
            <script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAL8dSTuXb92DWu0l78dtV4m4fC8psKeV4",
    authDomain: "groupinger-users.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://groupinger-users.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "groupinger-users",
    storageBucket: "groupinger-users.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "432661298034"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  </script>
  <script>
  window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign- in-button', { 
  'size': 'invisible', 
  'callback': function(response) { 
  // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber. 
  onSignInSubmit(); 
  } 
  });   firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber("+91XXXXXXXXXX", window.recaptchaVerifier) 
    .then((confirmationResult) => { 
    // At this point SMS is sent. Ask user for code. 
    alert('A confirmation message was just sent.');
    var code = window.prompt('Please enter the 6 digit code'); 
    return confirmationResult.confirm(code); 
    }).then((result) => { 
    console.log(result); 
    // User is now signed in and accessible via result.user. 
    }).catch((error) => { 
    // Error occurred. 
    }); 
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

But it's not working.
I'm a real newbie on Firebase. Please somebody help.
(Note: you can also test it on Localhost.)
The code is live at https://GroupinGer.cu.ma/ph/
Also, I would like to show the user data(Phone number, UID etc.) In another file called details.html.
I tried this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Logged in</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      Your details are shown below.
      <br>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase.js"></script>
                <script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAL8dSTuXb92DWu0l78dtV4m4fC8psKeV4",
    authDomain: "groupinger-users.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://groupinger-users.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "groupinger-users",
    storageBucket: "groupinger-users.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "432661298034"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
<script>
    var credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(confirmationResult.verificationId, code);
        alert(credential);
        alert('nope.');
</script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Please have a look at it too.
Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: You can try checking console by visiting the given web address.

Comment: You should not post API Keys publicly.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you need to initialize a recaptchaVerifier like this:

```
window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-
in-button', {
  'size': 'invisible',
  'callback': function(response) {
   // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
   onSignInSubmit();
 }
});
```

Second, your code has syntax error. Try the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Firebase Phone Number Auth</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="verificationcode" value="enter verification">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()">
  </form>
  <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAL8dSTuXb92DWu0l78dtV4m4fC8psKeV4",
    authDomain: "groupinger-users.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://groupinger-users.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "groupinger-users",
    storageBucket: "groupinger-users.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "432661298034"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container');
  firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber("replace with your phone number with country code, start with +1 if US.", window.recaptchaVerifier) 
  .then(function(confirmationResult) {
    window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
    console.log(confirmationResult);
  });
  var myFunction = function() {
    window.confirmationResult.confirm(document.getElementById("verificationcode").value)
    .then(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For more details, you can refer to the phone auth part of firebase auth doc.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth

Comment: @user8984670 Updated, can you try again?

Comment: I want to add code like 
´firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)   .then(function() {     // Existing and future Auth states are now persisted in the current     // session only. Closing the window would clear any existing state even     // if a user forgets to sign out.     // ...     // New sign-in will be persisted with session persistence.     return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);   })   .catch(function(error) {     // Handle Errors here.     var errorCode = error.code;     var errorMessage = error.message;   });´ for staying lo

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: This is the last question of this topic. Please tell me how to alert the user data.

Comment: I didn't found any code to get logged in user's phone number in a variable, in Firebase docs.

Comment: Please help! Guys

Comment: Can I change the phone number? Do you have any idea how to update phone number?

Comment: is there a way to get code sent to user mobile? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74330246/get-sms-verification-code-sent-to-user-in-javascript-sent-from-firebase-signinwi